# How do I call 'cost' in this dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently doing the 100 days of code course on Udemy, and I have been given this code.

```
menu = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}
```

How do I call the 'cost' part?

Comment: What do you mean by "call"? The value is just a float, not a phone number.

Comment: How do you read any value from a dictionary? How do you read keys from a dictionary? How do you loop over values? Answer those questions, show some work, and you'll get there.

Comment: for key , val in menu.items():
     menu = val.get('cost')

If you meant to get the value of cost then this is the soln

Comment: If you know the key, you can access it with a suffix. For example, `menu["cappuccino"]` fetches the subdictionary for "cappuccino", and `menu["cappuccino"]["cost"]` extracts the value of the "cost" key within that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `menu['<name of item you want to get cost for>']['cost']`.

For example, `print(menu['espresso']['cost'])` should output `1.5`.